# Jquery Delay Redirect MVC ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone has example, How to redirect to a new page in Jquery with MVC?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done as Darin says. Note that you might want to use a relative uri. The easiest way is to define a variable that contains the base uri (I'm using Razor view engine in the example).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUri = '@Url.Content("~/")';

    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = basUri + 'new/url';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need jquery for this. It can be done using the `window.location.href` property which will redirect the browser to the given url:

```
window.location.href = '/new/url';
```

Answer (score 2):

to new page, do this:

```
window.location = 'welcome.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("action","Controller")';*It gets in the way*
```